# AWS Cognito LogOut

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to be logged out from Cognito. According to the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html, the URL must be something like

`https://DOMAIN.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id=CLIENT&logout_uri=https://myclient/logout`
where `logout_url` is the same as specified in Cognito App Settings.

The problem that I'm trying to make something really basic to check how it works and I'm using https://google.com as `logout_url`. When I paste the logout endpoint link to my browser, the error produces `Required String parameter 'redirect_url' is not present`. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect the user to just any URL on logout, it needs to be one of the sign-out URLs [configured in the OAuth client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html).

That said, I think you have a second problem. The GET request takes two parameters: `client_id` and `logout_uri`. Note: that is not `url`, it is `uri`. Same goes for the `redirect_uri`. I'd check your code carefully to make sure you are using the proper parameter names.